# SQL: Move expired data from one table to another using a trigger or similar

Tags: mysql

Ok still the noob.
I have a table that has a date added column (date_added) and a expire period column (expire_period).
The date added is the day the recorded was added and the expire period column is the number of days the record will expire, varies from 1 day to 180 days.

What I would like is some automation (trigger) on the MySQL server to move the expired row to another table of similar once the expiry date has been reached.

I have been able to obtain the records that have expired by:

```
SELECT * FROM `dk`.`claims` WHERE date_add(`date_added`, interval `expire_period` day) < date(now());
```

How do I use this to move the data across to a new table claims_expired automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a trigger, because the trigger fires on every modification and you don't want to run this job every time you modify data.

Rather, use the [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-overview.html) to run a job every day, based on the `WHERE` clause in your statement:

```
CREATE EVENT archive_claims
   ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
   COMMENT 'archives claims older than their expiry date'
DO 
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO old_claims SELECT * FROM dk.claims WHERE ....
   DELETE FROM dk.claims WHERE ....
END
```

If it only runs once per day (because you don't have any finer time resolution in your expiry logic), you won't have massive performance slow-down every time you run a modification.

Comment: what if taking data to another table is critical for him after it expires? I mean if he needs to transfer data immediately after it expires.

Comment: @Jaan The question doesn't suggest that's required, because the expiry is controlled by the number of days. If it is, he could make the period more frequent to match the resolution required by his logic.

Comment: Jaan is quite correct in stating that once the expiry date is achieved the record should be moved to the archived table.

Comment: +Jeremy. That example looks great and may be the answer to use in the mean time. But as Jaan says which I may have not implicitly said is there not a way to have it moved once it reaches the expired date. The database is accessed on a continual basis through all time zone in the world.

Comment: If you absolutely must remove a row when it expires, then the correct place to do that is in your application, when someone queries that row. Otherwise you could have a situation where your application reads a row *after* it has expired but *before* either a trigger or a scheduled event occurs. If your app can (or must) tolerate such situations, then at that point it becomes a performance tradeoff based on your required resolution and how much of a hit you need at table modification time. Is the data type `TIMESTAMP`? do you use microsecond resolution? do you *need* microsecond resolution?

Comment: +Jeremy.  It is a date stamp. Thinking what you have said above, I will make the application run to one time zone and have expiry set to happen midnight at that time zone. Thank you for your assistance and valuable input into the workings of it

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html). The [basic syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) is:

```
CREATE EVENT event_name
ON SCHEDULE period
DO BEGIN
...
END
```

In your case you can put your query in the DO-BEGIN-END block.